# Having trouble achieving specific CSS Grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout

I am trying to create a shopping cart page.  This is my goal:

[image: shopping cart image]

I though about using Flexbox since this is one dimensional layout, but wanted to get some practice with CSS Grid. I think CSS Grid is a good solution because I can see 6 unequal sized columns.  I think I'm close, but my spacing is way off.  This is what I have so far:

```css
.shopping-cart .product-row {
 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}


.shopping-cart .product-row .product-image  img {
    width: 100px;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-details   {
  display: inline-block;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 3;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-details .product-description  {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 20px 0px 0;
    width: 50%; 
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-quantity input {
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopping-cart">

    <div class="product-row">

        <div class="product-image">
                <img src="https://www.drivencoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Scandinavian-Blend-coffee.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="product-details">
            <div class="product-title">Coffee</div>
            <div class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price">12.99</div>
        <div class="product-quantity">
            <input type="number" value="2" min="1" />
        </div>

        <div clas="product-removal">
            <button class="remove-product">
                Remove
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="product-total-price">
            25.98
        </div>
    </div>




</div>
```

[Here's a code pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KEoQRa) of the same code

I think my problem is with `grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto)`.  It's creating 6 columns and each column is only as big as the content inside of it.  I'm just not sure how to achieve for accurate positioning.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: this site might help you out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: You can try creating an 8 column layout using `grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr)` and use `grid-column: span 3` for `product-details` element?

Comment: @kukkuz Yeah that worked pretty well.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comments to this question, you can try creating an 8-column layout using `grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr)` and use `grid-column: span 3` for `product-details` element - see demo below:

```css
.shopping-cart .product-row {
 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr); /* CHANGED */
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}


.shopping-cart .product-row .product-image  img {
    width: 100px;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-details   {
  display: inline-block;
  grid-column: span 3; /* CHANGED */
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-details .product-description  {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px 20px 0px 0;
    width: 50%; 
    line-height: 1.4em;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-quantity input {
    width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopping-cart">

    <div class="product-row">

        <div class="product-image">
                <img src="https://www.drivencoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Scandinavian-Blend-coffee.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="product-details">
            <div class="product-title">Coffee</div>
            <div class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price">12.99</div>
        <div class="product-quantity">
            <input type="number" value="2" min="1" />
        </div>

        <div clas="product-removal">
            <button class="remove-product">
                Remove
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="product-total-price">
            25.98
        </div>
    </div>




</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I will now.  Everyone's answers were very helpful and each taught me something new.  Thanks again @kukkuz.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to use the old methods:
Want to use the grid ?

```css
.row {
  display: block;
}

img, input {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img {
  width: 64px;
}

.amount {
  width: 56px;
}

.details {
  width: calc(100% - 64px * 5);
}

.col {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="shopping-cart">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col img"><img src="https://www.drivencoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Scandinavian-Blend-coffee.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="col details">
                    <div class="product-title">Coffee</div>
            <div class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">12.99</div>
        <div class="col amount"><input type="number" value="2" min="1" /></div>
        <div class="col"><button class="remove-product"> Remove </button></div>
        <div class="col">25.98</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used bootstrap to handle the issue.

**Bootstrap is very response** across various display sizes, take a look over the code below

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
                <img style="width: 100%;" src="https://www.drivencoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Scandinavian-Blend-coffee.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <div class="product-title">Coffee</div>
            <div class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">12.99</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="number" value="2" min="1" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <button class="remove-product">
                Remove
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2">
            25.98
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you are asking about a solution for *css grid*, but I think your first idea was better. A shopping cart is a LIST of elements from which some have a more or less fixed size and position and another, the description, needs to adapt depending on the width. That for me is a list of flex items with `flex-flow: row nowrap` adding a `flex: auto` to the description.

Also, there is no need for a headers row, as concepts are clear if you order them properly: Photo > description > Price x [Quantity] > Total > Actions.

I forked your pen to show you an example: https://codepen.io/jesuke/pen/aMYGdv

However if you think Headers are required, then what you are looking for is a *data table* with *fixed layout* I believe. The fixed Layout will give you that accurate positioning you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses grid template column names and assigning them where required. Some of the template settings use `minmax()` to allow for some flexibility. Of course, you should adjust these to fit your specifications.

The `product-details` section is set to `flex` with a `column` layout.

Included as well is the header portion from OP's image of the desired layout. This is set as a grid as well and the appropriate column names are assigned to the header labels.

Furthermore, some slight enchancements, are a slight indent on `product-title` (as shown in the supplied image from OP) and also pre-prending a `$` to the `product-price` value.

Benefits to named grid templates is that assignment is made easy as well as setting the grid cell values are easily edited without much thought to which numbered column am I editing, for example.

```css
.shopping-cart,
.product-row > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.shopping-cart {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.shopping-cart__header,
.shopping-cart .product-row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [product-image] 6rem [product-details] minmax(11rem, 24rem) [product-price] 5rem [product-quantity] 5rem [product-removal] 6rem [product-total-price] 5rem;
  grid-column-gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  align-items: center;
}

[class*="shopping-cart__header__label"] {
  text-align: center;
}

.shopping-cart__header__label-price {
  grid-column-start: product-price;  
}

.shopping-cart__header__label-quantity {
  grid-column-start: product-quantity;  
}

.shopping-cart__header__label-total {
  grid-column-start: product-total-price;  
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-image  img {
    width: 100%;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-image {
  grid-column-start: product-image;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-details {
  grid-column-start: product-details;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0.625rem;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-details .product-title {
  padding-left: 0.635rem;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-price {
  grid-column-start: product-price;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-quantity {
  grid-column-start: product-quantity;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-quantity input {
    width: 2.5rem;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-removal {
  grid-column-start: product-removal;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-total-price {
  grid-column-start: product-total-price;
}

.shopping-cart .product-row .product-total-price:before {
  content: '$';
}
```

```html
<div class="shopping-cart">
   <header class="shopping-cart__header">
     <span class="shopping-cart__header__label-price">Price</span>
     <span class="shopping-cart__header__label-quantity">Quantity</span>
     <span class="shopping-cart__header__label-total">Total</span>
   </header>
    <div class="product-row">

        <div class="product-image">
                <img src="https://www.drivencoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Scandinavian-Blend-coffee.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div class="product-details">
            <div class="product-title">Coffee</div>
            <div class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim  </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price">12.99</div>
        <div class="product-quantity">
            <input type="number" value="2" min="1" />
        </div>

        <div clas="product-removal">
            <button class="remove-product">
                Remove
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="product-total-price">
            25.98
        </div>
    </div>




</div>
```